# Track that who viewed the document in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, flow, microsoft-flow

How can I track the users in sharepoint that who viewed or downloaded the document from document library?

I do not have the admin access so could not access the complaience center.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom code to monitor document libraries, check the article and demo below:

[Query SharePoint change log with ChangeQuery and ChangeToken](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/query-sharepoint-change-log-with-changequery-and-changetoken)

Comment: The linked article doesn't seems to mention download/views. Could you elaborate @Hellofiona_MSFT

Comment: It does not capture the document view events in it. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee537784%28v%3doffice.15%29

Answer (score 0):

Azure Information Protection offers functionality to [monitor access of documents](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2018/07/29/aip-i-know-when-you-open-my-document-and-i-can-revoke-access-compliance-sales-seller-hero/).